# Error in my SQL syntax on SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I'm new to sql programming. For a computer science project I am trying to apply my knowledge of sql in some way. On SQL Fiddle, I am using the MySQL 5.6 database and I am having so much trouble building schema. This is what it keeps telling me:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[ Name varchar[15], Description varchar[50], Ranking int, ]' at
>   line 2"

I need help either learning how to use SQL Fiddle or how to build my schema. Thanks and my code is below.

```
CREATE TABLE food
(
    Name varchar(15),
    Description varchar(50),
    Ranking int,
); 
insert into food
values ('Watermelon', 'A yummy fruit', 9);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a comma after Ranking int.

Corrected Code:

```
CREATE TABLE food ( Name varchar(15), Description varchar(50), Ranking int ); 
INSERT INTO food values ('Watermelon', 'A yummy fruit', 9);
```

Comment: Also, I'll advise not to use columns names like `Name` or `Description`. I'm not a MySql guy but I'll bet at least one of them is a reserved word.